# Refit not working (Github API)

Tags: c#, .net, rest, github-api, refit

I am trying to figure out how to use the Refit library to make GET requests but I do not know why it is not working. I am following the example on the refit github page. What am I  missing? It seems like the GetUser("octocat") method is not working. I've tried searching for other examples on how to use refit but wasn't able to find anything.

```
    private static async void getUser()
    {

        var gitHubApi = RestService.For<IGitHubApi>("https://api.github.com");


        var octocat = await gitHubApi.GetUser("octocat");
```

}

```
public class User
{

    [JsonProperty("login")]
    public string Login { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("avatar_url")]
    public string AvatarUrl { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("gravatar_id")]
    public string GravatarId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("url")]
    public string Url { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("html_url")]
    public string HtmlUrl { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("followers_url")]
    public string FollowersUrl { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("following_url")]
    public string FollowingUrl { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("gists_url")]
    public string GistsUrl { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("starred_url")]
    public string StarredUrl { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("subscriptions_url")]
    public string SubscriptionsUrl { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("organizations_url")]
    public string OrganizationsUrl { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("repos_url")]
    public string ReposUrl { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("events_url")]
    public string EventsUrl { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("received_events_url")]
    public string ReceivedEventsUrl { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("site_admin")]
    public bool SiteAdmin { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("company")]
    public string Company { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("blog")]
    public string Blog { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("location")]
    public string Location { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("email")]
    public object Email { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("hireable")]
    public object Hireable { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("bio")]
    public object Bio { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("public_repos")]
    public long PublicRepos { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("public_gists")]
    public long PublicGists { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("followers")]
    public long Followers { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("following")]
    public long Following { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("created_at")]
    public System.DateTimeOffset CreatedAt { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("updated_at")]
    public System.DateTimeOffset UpdatedAt { get; set; }
}

interface IGitHubApi
{


    [Get("/users/{user}")]
    Task<User> GetUser(string user);
}
```

Comment: Your endpoint is not correct. it should be /users/:username
see https://developer.github.com/v3/users/#get-a-single-user

Comment: It doesn't seem like that worked. I am getting the same issue.

Comment: My bad it is indeed /users/<username>... what are you getting as a response/exception?

Comment: I am not getting a response/exception. Code runs successfully but everytime I try to print  octocat.login after the getUser method I don't get any output on the console.

Comment: you just need to sed UserAgent to HttpClient if you are using Github Api

Comment: please take a look at this [article](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/type-safe-rest-refit-naushad-warsi/) to better understand Refit.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to query GitHub API you need to set a User-Agent

There's 2 way to do this with Refit:

**1 - Set the headers on your contract**

```
[Headers("User-Agent: My Favorite User Agent!")]
public interface IGitHubApi
{
    [Get("/users/{user}")]
    Task<User> GetUser(string user);
}
```

**2 - Use a HttpClient and set it there**

```
var httpClient = new HttpClient();
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "My Favorite User Agent!");
httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.github.com");
var gitHubApi = RestService.For<IGitHubApi>(httpClient);
var user = await gitHubApi.GetUser("octocat");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Github API than You need to set the UserAgent in the Header,
just as follows,

```
            {
                BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.github.com"),
                DefaultRequestHeaders = {UserAgent = { ProductInfoHeaderValue.Parse("NakWarsi")}}    //here I have put my username("NakWarsi") what you need to replace with your username 
            };
            _restApiService = RestService.For<IGitHubApi>(_client);
```

Here I have created a sample project using Github [take a look for detailed information](https://github.com/NakWarsi/Simplified_RestSample)